# javascript firefox sdk: get domain without subdomain

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

what is an easy way to get the domain without the subdomain.

For example in this URL: `http://a.b.hllo.co.uk` I want to retrieve `hllo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the [nsIEffectiveTLDService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIEffectiveTLDService) for this. It's basically a giant list of special-cases maintained by mozilla such as the mentioned `.co.uk` domain and used for same-basedomain (as opposed same-origin) policies such as cookies.

Some of its functionality is also exposed in the [sdk/url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/url#getTLD%28url%29) module.

Comment: Wow very nice! I didn't know of this. It would be nice to see an example with the question askers context :P I found some examples here though: https://github.com/search?l=javascript&q=nsIEffectiveTLDService&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: really cool. I ended up spliting the host on "." and getting the entry before the TLD, then padding it to the tld.

Comment: @David天宇Wong can you please post your final solution, it would help me out :)

Comment: I did it with the firefox addon sdk: https://github.com/mimoo/FirefoxTimeTracker/blob/master/lib/main.js#L83

there is a URL function that gets the TLD out of the url. Maybe you can use it outside of the sdk

Comment: ah, nice, didn't know that was exposed through the sdk

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can get [image]

So you have to just do string manipulation on that one I would think. Does'nt look like it auotmatically gets it, but i could be wrong.

Comment: yep, and even a string manipulation looks like it would get pretty big and cumbersome. I was looking for a canonical way of doing this.